# Render my react component inside a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, material-ui

I am using **React 18**, **Material UI version 5**, and **nanostores version 0.7.4**. I wrote a hook named `useApi.tsx` which initialize a new axios instance for me whenever I am using this hook. Now inside this hook I defined a interceptor to listen to the errors. It works perfectly fine and no matter what is the error it calls `responseErrorHandler` method. here is the code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Notification } from '../components/Notification/Notification.component';

export function useApi() {
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL,
    });

    api.interceptors.response.use(null, responseErrorHandler);

    return { api };
}

function responseErrorHandler(error) {
    <Notification
        color="error"
        text="Something went wrong, please try again ..."
    />;

    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

And now here is the `Notification` component code:

```
import {
    Alert,
    AlertColor,
    Snackbar,
    SnackbarCloseReason,
} from '@mui/material';
import { useStore } from '@nanostores/react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { NotificationStateStore } from './Notification.store';

export function Notification({
    text,
    color,
    autoHideDuration = 6000,
}: {
    text: string;
    color: AlertColor;
    autoHideDuration?: number;
}) {
    const { actions, states } = NotificationStateStore;
    const notificationState = useStore(states.notificationState);
    const handleClose = (
        event: Event | React.SyntheticEvent<any, Event>,
        reason?: SnackbarCloseReason,
    ) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
            return;
        }
        actions.closeNotification();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        actions.showNotification();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Snackbar
            open={notificationState}
            autoHideDuration={autoHideDuration}
            onClose={handleClose}
        >
            <Alert
                onClose={handleClose}
                severity={color}
                sx={{ width: '100%' }}
            >
                {text}
            </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
    );
}
```

As you can see I called `actions.showNotification();` to show the notification to the user and here is the code inside the `Notification.store.ts`:

```
import { action, atom } from 'nanostores';

const notification = atom<boolean | undefined>();
const showNotification = action(
    notification,
    'showNotification',
    (state) => {
        state.set(true);
    },
);
const closeNotification = action(
    notification,
    'closeNotification',
    (state) => {
        state.set(false);
    },
);

export const NotificationStateStore = {
    states: { notificationState: notification },
    actions: { showNotification, closeNotification },
};
```

My problem is that it won't work, I mean it wont show the notification in the frontend. Here you can see my code in github: https://github.com/kasir-barati/open-ai-summaries/tree/d717f7e64d9e529f6d6c2aa698b464814512b29e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to render a React component inside a regular JavaScript function (`responseErrorHandler`) and not even returning it.
You can manage the state of the notification outside of the responseErrorHandler and use it in a component.

Tthe `NotificationStateStore` stores the notification text and color:

```
import { AlertColor } from '@mui/material';
import { action, atom } from 'nanostores';

type NotificationState = {
    open: boolean;
    text: string;
    color: AlertColor;
    autoHideDuration?: number;
};
export type Notification = Omit<NotificationState, 'open'>;

const notification = atom<NotificationState>();
const showNotification = action(
    notification,
    'showNotification',
    (state, notification: Notification) => {
        const { autoHideDuration = 6000, ...rest } = notification;
        state.set({ ...rest, autoHideDuration, open: true });
    },
);
const closeNotification = action(
    notification,
    'closeNotification',
    (state) => {
        state.set(undefined);
    },
);

export const NotificationStateStore = {
    states: { notification },
    actions: { showNotification, closeNotification },
};
```

`responseErrorHandler` uses the `showNotification` action:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { NotificationStateStore } from '../components/Notification/Notification.store';

export function useApi() {
    const api = axios.create({
        baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL,
    });

    api.interceptors.response.use(null, responseErrorHandler);

    return { api };
}

function responseErrorHandler(error) {
    const { actions } = NotificationStateStore;

    actions.showNotification({
        color: 'error',
        text: 'Something went wrong, please try again ...',
    });
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

`Notification` component uses the new state structure and render it inside your application root component:

```
import { Alert, Snackbar, SnackbarCloseReason } from '@mui/material';
import { useStore } from '@nanostores/react';
import { NotificationStateStore } from './Notification.store';

export function Notification() {
    const { actions, states } = NotificationStateStore;
    const notificationState = useStore(states.notification);
    const handleClose = (
        event: Event | React.SyntheticEvent<any, Event>,
        reason?: SnackbarCloseReason,
    ) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
            return;
        }
        actions.closeNotification();
    };

    //  We need this if since if notificationState is undefined it cannot render the component.
    if (!notificationState) {
        return <></>;
    }

    return (
        <Snackbar
            open={notificationState.open}
            autoHideDuration={notificationState.autoHideDuration}
            onClose={handleClose}
        >
            <Alert
                onClose={handleClose}
                severity={notificationState.color}
                sx={{ width: '100%' }}
            >
                {notificationState.text}
            </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
    );
}
```

in you application, or other component where you want to render the notification:

```
function App() {
  // ...
  return (
    <>
      {/* Your other components */}
      <Notification />
    </>
  );
}
```